# Key Error when key is in dictionary

Tags: python, exif, keyerror

Just trying to pull some lat/lon info from EXIF data on a bunch of photos, but code is throwing a `KeyError` even though that key is used (successfully) later on to print specific coordinates.

Dictionary in question is "`tags`" - `'GPS GPSLatitude'` and `'GPS GPSLongitude'` are both keys in `tags.keys()`; I've triple checked.

So any intuition on why `tags['GPS GPSLatitude']` & `tags['GPS GPSLongitude']` are throwing key errors?

```
import os
import exifread

output = dict()
output['name'] = []
output['lon'] = []
output['lat'] = []

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".JPG"):
        full_path = path + file
        print (file) #check to ensure all files were found
        output['name'].append(file) #append photo name to dictionary
        f = open(full_path, 'rb') #open photo
        tags = exifread.process_file(f) #read exifdata
#       lon = tags['GPS GPSLongitude'] #this + next line = one method
#       output['lon'].append(lon)
#       output['lat'].append(tags['GPS GPSLatitude']) # = cleaner second method
        for tag in tags.keys():
            if tag in ('GPS GPSLongitude','GPS GPSLatitude'):
                print ("Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, tags[tag])) #successfully prints lat/lon coords with 'GPS GPSLongitude' and 'GPS GPSLatitude' as keys
```

UPDATE:

Here's the output of `print (tags.keys())` -- you'll see `GPS GPSLatitude` and `GPS GPSLongitude` in there. Also, have manually checked all the photos in the subset I'm using have GPS data.

`dict_keys(['GPS GPSImgDirection', 'EXIF SceneType', 'MakerNote Tag 0x0006', 'GPS GPSDestBearing', 'Thumbnail XResolution', 'EXIF BrightnessValue', 'GPS GPSAltitude', 'GPS GPSLongitude', 'EXIF LensSpecification', 'GPS GPSAltitudeRef', 'GPS GPSSpeedRef', 'GPS GPSDestBearingRef', 'EXIF WhiteBalance', 'Thumbnail ResolutionUnit', 'EXIF FocalLengthIn35mmFilm', 'EXIF SceneCaptureType', 'Image Model', 'MakerNote Tag 0x0008', 'Image Make', 'EXIF ShutterSpeedValue', 'MakerNote Tag 0x0007', 'EXIF ExifImageWidth', 'EXIF LensModel', 'Image YResolution', 'EXIF ComponentsConfiguration', 'Image GPSInfo', 'EXIF ISOSpeedRatings', 'EXIF ExposureMode', 'EXIF Flash', 'EXIF FlashPixVersion', 'GPS GPSLatitudeRef', 'EXIF ExposureBiasValue', 'Thumbnail JPEGInterchangeFormatLength', 'Thumbnail Compression', 'Image YCbCrPositioning', 'EXIF MakerNote', 'EXIF FNumber', 'JPEGThumbnail', 'MakerNote Tag 0x0001', 'EXIF ColorSpace', 'EXIF SubSecTimeDigitized', 'Thumbnail JPEGInterchangeFormat', 'MakerNote Tag 0x0004', 'EXIF SubjectArea', 'Image ResolutionUnit', 'EXIF SensingMethod', 'Image DateTime', 'Image Orientation', 'EXIF ExifVersion', 'Image ExifOffset', 'GPS GPSImgDirectionRef', 'MakerNote Tag 0x0014', 'Thumbnail YResolution', 'EXIF DateTimeOriginal', 'MakerNote Tag 0x0005', 'EXIF LensMake', 'EXIF DateTimeDigitized', 'MakerNote Tag 0x0003', 'GPS GPSTimeStamp', 'EXIF ExposureTime', 'GPS Tag 0x001F', 'EXIF SubSecTimeOriginal', 'GPS GPSLatitude', 'Image Software', 'EXIF ApertureValue', 'GPS GPSDate', 'EXIF ExposureProgram', 'GPS GPSSpeed', 'EXIF ExifImageLength', 'EXIF MeteringMode', 'GPS GPSLongitudeRef', 'EXIF FocalLength', 'Image XResolution'])`

Traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-949ba89a1248> in <module>()
     16 #        lon = tags["GPS GPSLongitude"]
     17 #        output['lon'].append(lon)
---> 18         output['lat'].append(tags['GPS GPSLatitude'])
     19         for tag in tags.keys():
     20             if tag in ('GPS GPSLongitude','GPS GPSLatitude'):

KeyError: 'GPS GPSLatitude'
```

Link to photo: [https://drive.google.com/a/cornell.edu/file/d/0B1DwcbbAH1yuTEs0cUhhODdlNnc/view](https://drive.google.com/a/cornell.edu/file/d/0B1DwcbbAH1yuTEs0cUhhODdlNnc/view])

Output of the print statement for this photo

```
IMG_6680.JPG
Key: GPS GPSLongitude, value [76, 29, 353/20]
Key: GPS GPSLatitude, value [42, 26, 5069/100]
```

Comment: can you print tags.keys()? and can you also add the full traceback?

Comment: I can't reproduce your results using http://www.geospatialexperts.com/images/geotagging%20flooding.JPG as the JPG file. Can you try using that file? Can you post the file you *are* using?

Comment: when you say *"'GPS GPSLatitude' and 'GPS GPSLongitude' are both keys in tags.keys();"* are you sure it is in **all of the tags dicts**? Realize that you are looping over many images so while they might be in the first image it is not guaranteed  to be in all of them.

Comment: *output in update in original question. thanks!

Comment: If python says the key isn't in the dictionary, it's safe to assume it is indeed not in the dictionary. Can you include the full stacktrace of the error, as that likely has more clues to the problem.

Comment: Latitude Ref gives a reference point from which to calculate degrees; not the coordinates, in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GPS GPSLatitude` and `GPS GPSLongitude` may not be present in all tag dicts.

Instead of accessing keys as `tags['GPS GPSLatitude']` & `tags['GPS GPSLongitude']` , you can also access these as `tags.get('GPS GPSLatitude')` & `tags.get('GPS GPSLongitude')` This wil return `None` instead of throwing error, where you can apply if-else condition also to verify where these keys are not present.

Comment: @E.Case I'd recommend (for testing purposes) checking when one of the values is None and printing some kind of warining / info stating that the data was not available on that image.  You could then print out `tags.keys()` for that specific image and see if it was indeed missing for that image.

Comment: for example `if output['lat'][-1] is None: print(file,"had no lat property", ("GPS GPSLatitude" in tags.keys()))`

Answer (score 0):

I think @BryanOakley has the right idea. If the key isn't in the dict, it isn't there. (Those fields are optional, and some files might not have the data.) So you can use the `dict.get(key, default=None)` approach, and replace the Key Error with a default value.

```
jpegs = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith('.JPG')]
locns = []

for jpeg in jpegs:
    with open(jpeg,'rb') as jpf:
        exif = exifread.process_file(jpf)
        lat = exif.get('GPS GPSLatitude', 'Not available')
        lon = exif.get('GPS GPSLongitude', 'Not available')
        locns.append((lat, lon))
```

Comment: you have completely changed the format of the `output` variable, in a way that loses reference to which file has which data I may add.